# Insect/cocoon ID?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera

Can anyone ID this? We’re in the Rocky Mountains, Western US. We found it stuck to the wall of our garage, a few feet up, hidden behind a snow sled. It seems to be covered, or surrounded, in what looks like mouse hair. Is it a moth? It’s hard to see scale, but altogether about the size of a thumb.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would guess this is the [cocoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pupa#Cocoon) of a moth in the subfamily [Arctiina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctiinae_(moth)) in the [Erebidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erebidae) family.

For example, see this example of an [Isabella Tiger Moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrharctia_isabella) cocoon in Kent Co., Maryland from [The Maryland Biodiversity Project](https://www.marylandbiodiversity.com/viewSpecies.php?species=2485):

[image]

<sup>Credit: [Nancy Martin](https://www.marylandbiodiversity.com/viewSpecies.php?species=2485)</sup>

You can find additional images of various species [here](https://bugguide.net/node/view/770467), [here](https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2014/04/09/cocoon-woolly-bear-believe/), [here](http://somethingscrawlinginmyhair.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Isabella.moth.cocoons.jpg), and [here](https://hiveminer.com/Tags/arctiidae%2Ccocoon/Recent) (seen without the cocoon).

According to [here](https://www.butterfliesandmoths.org/species/Pyrrharctia-isabella), *Pyrrharctia isabella* (or the Isabella Tiger Moth shown above) *is* sometimes found in the Rocky Mountain region of the US, but I am not knowledgeable enough about these pupae to definitively point toward a species.

Based on the [experiences of many others](https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2012/11/15/caterpillar-hairs-produce-human-rash/), I would advise not touching this with bare hands or clothing.